# Scaling UIImageView in a UIScrollView causing offset when sliding the image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am trying to scale a `UIImageView` using a pinch gesture as in the code below:

```
- (void)scaleImage:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        previousScale = 1.0;
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageViewPic.frame.size.width, imageViewPic.frame.size.height);
        return;
    }
    CGFloat newScale = 1.0 - (previousScale - [recognizer scale]);
    CGAffineTransform currentTransformation = imageViewPic.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransformation, newScale, newScale);
    imageViewPic.transform = newTransform;
    previousScale = [recognizer scale];
}
```

My problem is that if I try to move the newly scaled image it makes an offset from the bottom and the right (as in the image below), and I can't move it down completely from the top and the left (there are areas that I don't see). What am I doing wrong? I am getting the new width and height that the image view gets from the transformation, aren't these values the new values that I should use in the scroll view content?

[image]

Comment: I hope that someone really helps you in this since I am facing the same problem.